# Use gradle buildSrc for Dependency Management

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

Would it be useful to manage multi-module gradle dependencies in `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/Dependencies.gradle` ? What are the downsides?

As an example:

buildSrc/src/main/groovy/myproject/Dependencies.groovy

```
package myproject

class Dependencies {
    static Map<String, String> versions = [
        junit: '4.12'
    ]
    static Map<String, String> libraries = [
        "junit:junit:${versions.junit}"
    ]
}
```

sub/build.gradle:

```
import example.Dependencies

dependencies {
    testCompile Dependencies.libraries
}
```

Result:

- *Pro: IDE (IntelliJ) jumps to definition, supports code completion*
- Pro: Without changes to files in buildSrc, execution should be faster
- Pro: Easy to use version number in buildScript block
- Pro: Can use plain Groovy or gradle api if necessary
- **Con: In a multiproject build, every change triggers rebuild of all modules, not just truly affected ones**
- Con: location `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/myproject/Dependencies.groovy` is quite remote, could be optimized though to `buildSrc/src/Dependencies`

What do others think? Moving more gradle build logic to groovy files in buildSrc may also be useful for other configuration. The main advantage over `apply from` being that IDE fully supports jump to declaration, types, code completion.

I am aware of these alternatives:

- Use a composite build to define a plugin project as a separate gradle project in the same repository (use `includeBuild()` in `settings.gradle`)
- Keep version numbers in `gradle.properties`
- Keep version numbers as variables in root `build.gradle`, typically in ext {} block
- Use Spring dependency management plugin (optionally with BOM)
- Use new configurations per dependency (group)

Comment: One issue you may run into is tasks rerunning (such as any other tasks you have defined in `buildSrc`) due to classpath changes whenever you change a version. This can affect the incrementality of your build and reduce cache hits if you use the build cache.

Comment: good point. Cache hit ration will be lower than optimum in occasional cases, but I think with "normal" usage that should not be a problem. If the size of a repo was massive (1000s of packages), then the mere lack of isolation of the dependency declaration may be a problem. Ideally a change in dependency(-version) would only affect those modules using that dependency. Not sure if that ideal can be achieved and at the same time avoiding duplicate declaration, maybe only with a meta-buildscript generating build files.

Comment: Another small issue I found is that any IDE might not auto-refresh when files within buildSrc change, because that is more unusual than build.gradle changing.

Comment: This is also mentioned in this article: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/using-buildsrc-for-custom-logic-in-gradle-builds/